# How can I make fasterXml ObjectMapper put a format property into schema for fields of the type long

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, objectmapper

How can I make an `ObjectMapper` set the `format` field for some properties in the generated schema of a class?

I'm trying to generate a schema for a java class using a `FasterXml` library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-jsonSchema</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Test:

```
@SneakyThrows
@Test
public void test() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SchemaFactoryWrapper schemaVisitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    objectMapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(objectMapper.constructType(MyClass.class), schemaVisitor);
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schemaVisitor.finalSchema()));
}

@Data
public static class MyClass {
    private int myInt;
    private long myLong;
}
```

The result is like this:

```
{
   "type":"object",
   "id":"urn:jsonschema:........:MyClass",
   "properties":{
      "myInt":{
         "type":"integer"
      },
      "myLong":{
         "type":"integer"
      }
   }
}
```

Both types are good, but I'd like to have `"format": "int64"` set for the property `myLong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Json Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#numeric-types) does not introduce `int64` type. There are only `number` and `integer` types. Take a look at the enum [JsonFormatTypes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsonFormatVisitors/JsonFormatTypes.html). `JsonSchema` module uses it. To extend it you would have to extend a lot of classes and somehow trick internal mechanism to replace `integer` with `int64` which at the end would generate misleading schema which would be understandable only for you. All other libs and tools do not recognise it. I propose to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyDescription` annotation for `long` property:

```java
class MyClass {

    private int myInt;

    @JsonPropertyDescription("int64")
    private long myLong;
}
```

Which will generate something like this:

```json
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:example:MyClass",
  "properties" : {
    "myInt" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    },
    "myLong" : {
      "type" : "integer",
      "description" : "int64"
    }
  }
}
```